# Data rate and frame rate property

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I convert a file using ffmpeg command in which audio and video bitrate are specified.

But when i play the converted file into totem player or vlc media player then audio and video bitrate in properties section are being displayed "N/A" whereas it must be same as these are specified in command.

```
ffmpeg -i 'in.wmv' -s 1280x720 -b 256 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 2 'output.mp4'
```

What is the exact issue? Please help me?

Comment: I've updated your question and my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show us the exact command you are using.  *"It doesn't work"* is not enough information to diagnose problems with something is *wildly* complex as `ffmpeg`.  Also, if possible, linking to the resulting media file would help too.

The resulting media, if successfully encoded, *must* have an audio and video bit-rate.  The problem very well my be with the tools you are using to read the file.

---

## Update!

It looks to me like you forgot the units on the `-b` parameter.  Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i 'in.wmv' -s 1280x720 -b 256k -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 2 'output.mp4'
```

Note how the `-b` switch value has a `k` on it.

Also, I've just got to say, the size 1280x720 is awfully large for such a low bit-rate.  I would highly recommend a size either 1/2 or 1/3 of 1280x720, or increasing the video bit-rate to 512k or 768k.  You are not going to get what you think you are going to get with such values.

Comment: Hello Thompson, 
Thanks for reply.

Command is as follows:-

 ffmpeg -i 'in.wmv' -s 1280x720 -b 256 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 2 'output.mp4'